# How do I go to a file in vim/nerdtree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to transition to vim, but I'm having a hard time mapping over some functionalities in pycharm over to vim.

The first being how do I directly go to a filepath. In pycharm, I believe it is cmd-shift P. You'll type the file-path and it'll take you there. I *think* there's auto-complete too?

Like -- I know that there's a .css file I want to access. So I'd instinctively start typing: `cmd shift p .css` and this would return the .css files.

How do I do that in vim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`:edit` is the most basic command for editing an existing file.

```
:edit <your file name>
```

To get a list of all the files ending in ".css" use `:edit e *.css` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. See `:help c_CTRL-D` in Vim for more information.

`:find <file>` is a more powerful version of `:edit`. It searches for `<file>` from the directories listed in your `path` option. For example, if your current directory is `project` and the value of the `path` contains
`/path/to/project/**`, then `:find file.css` will search all the subdirectories of project for the "file.css".

There is also a plugin called "[ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)" that should be similar to what you used in pycharm.

For more information about file navigation, I highly recommend reading "[Death by a thousand files](https://vimways.org/2018/death-by-a-thousand-files/)", an excellent article by Romain Lafourcade.